# apache-jmeter-5.4.1 Server failed to start: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port 4000

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

In centos environment I setup a **rmi_keystore.jks** in master device  and copy it to the bin of Jmeter worker machine too.
In my master device's jmeter.properties file I only did below changes.

```
remote_hosts=10.54.225.200
server.rmi.localport=4000
```

However, In worker device, when I try to start the server.
by giving master's hostname is 10.54.225.190

```
cd apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin

./jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.54.225.190
```

below error occurs. The port 4000 is not in used though.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use different SERVER_PORT instead of default 1099 I believe you need to amend your setup to something like:

1. Slave: `jmeter-server -Jserver_port=4000`
2. Master: `jmeter -R 10.54.225.200:4000 -n -t test.jmx`

See [Using a different port](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#portchange) user manual entry for more details if needed.

If you want to customize further refer the following materials:

- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)
- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker)

Comment: Thank you Dimitri , earlier my port 4000 was not  open , now it's opened . Now I get Connection refused to host java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out . I am sure that my devices are in the same subnet and ports are open.